# How do you display the number of a post in a query?

Tags: query

I want to display the number of a post beside each post title in a query, such that it literally appears like this:

1. Post title one in query
2. Post title two in query
3. Post title three in query

How do I do this?

---

```
<?php

function ngtj_get_some_posts( $category_name )
{
    // set the criteria 
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 10,
         'post_type' => array('feature', 'post')
    );
    // return the object array of the posts.
    return get_posts( $args );
}
?>

  <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>



<?php


$posts_returned = ngtj_get_some_posts( 'CATEGORY_NAME' );



foreach ( $posts_returned as $post_returned )
{
      echo $post_returned->post_title.'<input style="text-align: center;" type="text" name="postnumber" size="1">'.$post_returned->ID.'<br>'.$post_returned->current_post.'<input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="post_one" />';



}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order number of the post in main query would be `$wp_query->current_post + 1` (if I remember right it counts from zero, but try and see). :)

Note that *literally* your example is ordered list, which might or might not have been intended via Markdown. In that case you need to adjust your loop for appropriate markup (`<ol><li>title here</li></ol>`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have tried this, and for some reason it's not working for me. I've created a query in my functions.php that outputs a list of posts, but the number of the post isn't displaying at all. I've edited my post to add in the code I'm using. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @EdmundHeaphy if you are using `get_posts()` then what you have is just "dumb" array of post items. It won't keep count for you, you'll have to do it yourself via PHP (which is tad outside of WP scope here :)

Comment: "if I remember right it counts from zero, but try and see" Correct, the build-in loop counter starts at `0` :-)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks again for your replies. Have worked it out using the solution above.